# Blank Questions in GRE

Tags: gre

[image]
question: for the second blank, because of "But" we can decide to put "justified" and it's clear that the others do not make sense. but for the first blank I think all three answers can be placed there.
the answer is "surprising"!

Comment: Given the GRE style of question, it is not ________ that the answer is *surprising*, as the other two might read oddly in the context.

Comment: why don't you think that the others can be correct Henry? could you please  explain more?

Comment: For the same reason as *surprising* being the best fit in my comment.  The other two do not quite fit.

Comment: You know, GRE is a reasoning exam and we should have a reason to eliminate the answers. You eliminate the others just because they do not fit in the blank. I think we can say "it can be irrelevant to put a portrait in an art museum". How can you reject this sentence? In my opinion if it is just fitting, "irrelevant" also fitted in the sentence.

Comment: It needs to fit the "since the subject matter ... high art" part too, and *irrelevant* does not.